# Expanded column height in left row depending on column height of right row

Tags: flutter

I am building a social media app with a commenting system. I want to draw a line (or something else) to the left side of the comment depending on the comments height. I built something like this:

```
Container(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage('someURL'),
            radius: 20,
            ),
            // Here I want e.g. a vertical line with a dynamic height depending on
            // height of the right side (the comment)
        ],
      )
      Expanded(
        Column(
          children: [
            Text('Name'),
            Text('Comment'), // Can be multiline and sets the height of the row
          ]
        )
      )
    ]
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Row and IntrinsicHeight to achieve it

```
class CommentCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Testing'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Name'),
                  IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: [
                        VerticalDivider(
                          width: 25,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Text(
                                'Some text'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```